# What are the lyrics to the song at the beginning of Flipnic: Ultimate Pinball?

Tags: flipnic-ultimate-pinball

Flipnic starts with a brilliant little song sung by two computers, with a digital monkey on screen fishing.  Depending on what the monkey catches, the song's ending changes.  For example, when the monkey catches three fish holding onto each other, the second voice cuts itself off and says 'OH MY GOD, IT'S A MIRACLE!', [as seen in this video](http://www.gamespot.com/users/vaejas/video_player?id=IyRgwTL65bsOujTd).

Does anyone know the full text of the main bit of the song?  And do you know all of the endings, along with what the monkey catches?  Any information is helpful, as all I have to go on are some possibly inaccurate statements made by a commenter at the hyperlink!

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right...

> Flipnic, Flipnic, won't you answer me? 
>   For I am wondering, how lucky am I today?
>
> Yes yes, I will answer for you, 
>   if you would like to know, 
>   I hope the best and here it is, 
>   (this part is different depending on the luck) today!

Answer (score 1):

Voice1:
Flipnic! Flipnic!
Could you answer me?
Will I have luck today,
will I have a wonderful day?
Voice2:
Yes, yes, I will answer for you
if you would like to know!
[If you had bad luck (monkey escape from a crocodile):
I hope the best and here it is.
You should not play flipnic today...]
[If you had small luck (monkey catch a rain boot)
I hope the best and here it is.
Your luck is getting better today!]
[If you had good luck (monkey catch a mediocre fish and dance)
I hope the best and here it is.
You will be all successful today!]
[If you had great luck (monkey catch a big fish and dance)
I hope the best and here it is.
You are incredibly lucky today!]
[If you were miraculous (monkey catch small, mediocre and big fish at once)
I hope the best and here...
Ohhh my god! It's a miracle!!]